# push notification does not work for ios and azure with specific token

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova

We are using Visual Studio to create an Apache Cordova app that is connected to an Azure Mobile Service .  We are using the Cordova Push Plugin to receive Notifications in our app.  We have created a JavaScript method in the Azure Mobile Service to send the notifications, this method is triggered by a scheduler.  Please note that the intention is to send each Notification to a particular device.

The notifications work perfectly for Android devices but not for the iOS devices.

In iOS the notification is not received however the method in Azure Mobile Service always returns “Success”.
If we set the Device Token to "Null" , then it works for iOS devices (but sends to all devices not just one).

Could anyone please help us to resolve this issue?

this is Push.Send() method in Azure

```
   push.send(result.DeviceID, payload, {
           success: function(pushResponse){
           //console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
           //update notification sent time-start
           var sqlUpdate = '';

          mssql.query(sqlUpdate, {
              success: function(results)
                {
                //response.json(statusCodes.OK, results);
                },
               error : function()
                {
                //response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                 }
         })
           //update notification sent time-end
           },
           error: function (pushResponse) {
               //console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
               }
        });
```

and this is my App registration Method in the app

```
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        //alert("device.platform" + device.platform);
        // Platform-specific registrations.
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            alert("device.platform : Android ");
            // Register with GCM for Android apps.
            pushNotification.register(
               app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,
               { 
                   "senderID": GCM_SENDER_ID, 
                   "ecb": "app.onNotificationGCM" 
               });
        } else if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
            // Register with APNS for iOS apps. 
            alert("device.platform : iOS ");
            pushNotification.register(
                app.tokenHandler,
                app.errorHandler, { 
                    "badge":"true",
                    "sound":"true",
                    "alert":"true",
                    "ecb": "app.onNotificationAPN"
                });

        }
        else if(device.platform === "Win32NT"){
            // Register with MPNS for WP8 apps.
            alert("Device platform Windows")
            pushNotification.register(
                app.channelHandler,
                app.errorHandler,
                {
                    "channelName": "MyPushChannel",
                    "ecb": "app.onNotificationWP8",
                    "uccb": "app.channelHandler",
                    "errcb": "app.ErrorHandler"
                });
        }
        // #endregion notifications-registration
```

Comment: Have you seen this article?  It might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879353.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But we already looked at that post. Even that post, the Device_ID set to Null. Do you have any other solutions?  Thanks again.